# NSManagedObject property is null

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a UIButton subclass in which I set a property `concert` to a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. When I set this property, I am sure that the `NSManagedObject` is not null and that it's properties aren't null. Also, the data of the object shows the correct data.

When using the `concert` later when the button is clicked and sent to the method as `sender`, I will cast the `sender` to my subclass of `UIButton` and the properties of the `concert` will now return null but the `concert` itself is not null. Also, the data will be `fault`.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

Here, I initialize my button:

`NFConcertButton *button = [NFConcertButton buttonWithConcert:concert tileSize:self.tileSize];`

In `initWithButton:tileSize:` (which is called by the static method) I store the concert for later use.

```
- (id)initWithConcert:(NFConcert *)concert tileSize:(CGSize)tileSize
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Store concert
        _concert = concert;

       /*
         <NFConcert: 0xde67eb0> (entity: Concert; id: 0xde63f60 <x-coredata://F027F762-2F30-4A43-898B-42ECC199DE97/Concert/p2> ; data: {
           band = "SomeBand";
         })
        */

        // concert is not null
        // concert.band is not null

        // .... //
    }

    return self;
}
```

When the button is pressed, the below method is called and the properties of `concert` are now null.

```
- (void)concertButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NFConcert *concert = ((NFConcertButton *) sender).concert;
    // <NFConcert: 0xde67eb0> (entity: Concert; id: 0xde63f60 <x-coredata://F027F762-2F30-4A43-898B-42ECC199DE97/Concert/p2> ; data: <fault>) => (null)
    // concert is not null.
    // concert.band is now null.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If I fetch the `NSManagedObject` again using the `objectId`, I will get the data and the properties will not return null. I don't understand why this would be necessary. Can anyone tell me?

The below will work.

```
NFConcert *concert = ((NFConcertButton *) sender).concert;
concert = (NFConcert *) [managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:concert.objectID error:nil];
```

Comment: Could you plz post the code related to the declaration of property concert?

Comment: @luyuan My property is declared like this `@property (nonatomic, strong) NFConcert *concert;`

Comment: @luyuan From Xcode 4.4 we don't need to synthesize the properties. I have not synthesized the property.

Comment: what's _concert? Have you declared it?

Comment: have you tried self.concert = concert;?

Comment: @luyuan If a property is not synthesized a default will be added when compiling. This one will be similar to `@synthesize concert = _concert;`. I did try `self.concert` but this gave me the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Apples default implementation of the Core Data stack, I no longer have this issue.
I believe this issue was caused by [`DataManager`](https://gist.github.com/922496) which I used to work with the Core Data stack.